# ELK - Unexpected query result

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a strange problem with this query, in fact, beyond the expected results, it seems to extract the events with rule.id: "100002".

Could someone explain to me where I went wrong?

```
    {
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "should":[
            {
               "wildcard":{
                  "rule.description":{
                     "value":"*PNP device*"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "match_phrase":{
                  "rule.id":{
                     "query":"111000",
                     "slop":0,
                     "zero_terms_query":"NONE",
                     "boost":1
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "match_phrase":{
                  "rule.id":{
                     "query":"111001",
                     "slop":0,
                     "zero_terms_query":"NONE",
                     "boost":1
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "range":{
                  "timestamp":{
                     "gte":"now-10m",
                     "lte":"now",
                     "format":"strict_date_optional_time"
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "adjust_pure_negative":true,
         "minimum_should_match":"1",
         "boost":1
      }
   }
}
```

The goal would be to extract the records that match the 111000 event or the 111001 event by checking if the string "*PNP device*" is present in rule.description filed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have all your constraints in a `bool/should` with `minimum_should_match: 1`, it means that you'll get all documents that match **at least one** of those constraints.

The query you're looking for is probably this one:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "rule.description": {
              "value": "*PNP device*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-10m",
              "lte": "now",
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "rule.id": ["111000", "111001"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```